# Optimal Length of a Python Function (Style)

Tags: python, function, optimization, styles

Perhaps this is not the correct place to ask this question, and part of me thinks that there is no real answer to it, but I'm interested to see what experienced Python users have to say on the subject:

For maximum readability, concision, and utility, what is a range for an optimal length of a Python function?  (Assuming that this function will be used in combination with other functions to do something useful.)

I recognize that this is incredibly dependent on the task at hand, but as a Sophomore Comp. Sci. major, one of the most consistent instructions from professors is to write programs that are comprised of short functions so as to break them up into "simple", discrete tasks.

I've done a big of digging, including through the Python style guide, but I haven't come up with a good answer. If there are any experienced Python users that would like to weigh in on this subject, I would appreciate the insight.  Thanks.

Comment: When you write an essay, how long do you make each paragraph? Does how many lines the paragraph is matter more than what it is saying?

Comment: I generally prefer to make sure I can view the whole function on a medium resolution display (in landscape mode) without scrolling. This is especially so with Python (no closing brace) as it's easy to see where each function ends. In most regards, the factors affecting Python will be the same those already made here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129599/best-rule-for-maximum-function-size

Comment: I suppose that part of my intent in asking this is to get some insight into the importance of how something is said and the relationship that has to what is being said.  I'm wondering if the "many, discrete functions" thing is a quirk of programming in an academic environment, or a useful real world lesson.

Comment: @austinsherron Oh it's most definitely useful. Small "packages" of code are easier to maintain and *unit test*. They tend to look nicer too. But it's hard to say there's an optimal length, once again it depends what the function is doing. Don't feel pressured to make functions small and concise all the time; do what makes sense to you.

Comment: Seven lines, obviously.

Answer (score 7):

I'm sure a lot of people have strong opinions about this, but for new programmers a good rule of thumb is to try and keep it below 10-20 lines. A better rule of thumb is that a function should do one thing and do that one thing well. If it becomes really long, it is likely doing more than one thing and can be broken down into several functions.